# Docker failed to solve: executor failed running. exit code: 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, docker-image

I am trying to dockerize my Django project with the following Dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip lock -r > requirements.txt \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["ls"]
```

Error

```
#0 5.012 41 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#0 5.012 Need to get 28.9 MB of archives.
#0 5.012 After this operation, 32.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#0 5.012 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update 
    && apt-get upgrade pip     && pip install --upgrade pip     && 
pip lock -r > requirements.txt     && pip install -r 
requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I am getting this error trying to `docker-compose up`. I think it's because of incorrect command inputs of `python:3.9-bullseye` distribution. I am new to Docker and trying to figure out what the Linux commands are. Please help me correct this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By checking the log output

```
#0 7.873 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

You should pass the flag `-y` in order to auto accept the installation of packages in apt related commands.

So you should try something like this

```
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
```

Comment: @Docker my answer solved your original issue. You should instead accept this answer and create a new question, with the new error. Since the new error has nothing to do with your previous one

Comment: @Docker Excuse my tone. Didnt mean to sound offensive. Just wanted to provide guidance. Create a new question and I would be gladly to assist you further :)

Comment: Respect you bro!

Comment: I will, but in 90 minutes. I can't post right now